# JavaDB dual installation

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish, javadb

on WIN XP SP3 and Netbeans 6.7.1 IDE,

I have installed Java SDK 6.17 which includes JavaDB. I set the JavaDB directory to ...\Java\JavaDB at the Java installation script with %DERBY_HOME% set accordingly and %PATH% including %DERBY_HOME%\bin

Later on I installed GlassFish-V3 Prelude which - surprise surprise - comes with its own JavaDB and silently installs that into a JavaDB directory under the GlassFish path.

Q's

1. I don't want to have duplicates. Can
   I remove one of these installations
   without spoiling Netbeans.
2. How can I verify which of the two
   JavaDB's Netbeans is actually using
3. Can I eventually configure GlassFish
   in a way to use the JavaDB I
   installed as part of the SDK

Thanks for any hints (as on superuser.com I didn't get any replies :-( )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't want to have duplicates. Can I remove one of these installations without spoiling Netbeans.

If really you want to remove one of them, I'd suggest to remove the one that comes with your JDK and to leave the one bundled with GlassFish v3 (GlassFish expects it to be there when using some commands which can be extremely handy, e.g. during development). But honestly,  I wouldn't spend too much time for the 4.5 MB extra space used.

> How can I verify which of the two JavaDB's Netbeans is actually using

To verify, go to the **Services** tab, expand the **Databases** node and **right-click** on  **Java DB** and select **Properties...**. You should get the following window:

[alt text http://netbeans.org/images_www/articles/65/ide/java-db/javadb-props.png](http://netbeans.org/images_www/articles/65/ide/java-db/javadb-props.png)

As documented in [Working with the Java DB (Derby) Database](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/java-db.html), *"If you have the GlassFish Server registered in your NetBeans IDE installation, Java DB will already be registered for you."*

> Can I eventually configure GlassFish in a way to use the JavaDB I installed as part of the SDK

I don't know, but... why would you do that, why is it such a concern, don't you think you're wasting your time? Now, as I said, if this is really an issue, remove the version bundled with your JDK instead.

PS: GlassFish v3 is out, GlassFish v3 prelude is outdated, you should upgrade.

Comment: very helpful answer - thanks a lot. In fact my Netbeans in its infinite wisdom chose to use the DB bundled with the Java SDK - maybe because this was installed before Glassfish. Thanks for the add'l hint on GFv3Prelude being outdated (+1) ... my goodness I have to upgrade quicker than I can write a "Hello World" in Assembler - and YES I care about 4M5 - as a matter of principle - and thanks to all you lovely people I didn't have to waste time :-)))

Answer (score 0):

MikeD!

After many years, I am using **NetBeans** again. As I realized many features are included but others get "lost". I am planning to install several versions.
In **NetBeans 6.7.1**, to know what version of **Java DB NetBeans** is using, **right click the Java DB node and ckeck the properties.**
The path next to the **label Java DB Installation** tells you what installation is currently in use.
The path next to the label **Database Location** is used as the value for the **property derby.system.home**. This property **tells Java DB where to create/find** the individual databases folders. Besides, this folder holds two files called **derby.properties** and **derby.log.**
**derby.properties** establishes **persistently system-wide properties**.

Do not worry about duplicates. As you can see **NetBeans** uses 1 at a time. Nevertheless, as a recommendation, choose an installation and stick to it. During my tests I changed the path to the **Java DB Installation** several times and played with the user authentication properties inside derby.properties and eventually **NetBeans** could not create new databases in the regular way. So, I had to re-install **NetBeans** (I use the OS independent zip).

Regarding **GlassFish**, I have not experimented yet. But, it is reasonable to think that there is some limited set of options about using a different version of **Java DB**. For example, **NetBeans 6.7.1 Java DB** support **fails** if you set the **netbeans_jdkhome property** so that it points to a **JDK version equal or higher than 1.7.0**. That tells us something, right?

I will try to tell you anything useful I find out during my tests.

George